# How to convert to .amr using Wavepad Audio Editor?

Tags: audio, conversion, audio-conversion, amr

According to https://www.nch.com.au/wavepad/kb/1414.html WavePad both reads and exports/saves to .amr but how?

This is how my save dialogue looks:

[image: save dialogue]

No .amr-option there as far as I can see? Looked through some of the options but didn't find anything there either.

Currently I export to .wav and use some other tool when I want .amr but that is cumbersome.

Comment: You should ask their support. Probably the free version doesn't support the full list of formats.

Comment: @DavidPostill Other functions that are not included in the free version are still in the program but when you select them you get a message about paying, which is both "fair" and rational.